# Equation exceeds single column of IEEE template

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

The equation is attached here.

```
\begin{multline}\label{eq6}
MI\left( {E,{E^t},E_k^n,E_l^m} \right) = 
\sum\limits_i {\sum\limits_j {p\left( {{E_i=0},E_j^t=0,E_k^n=0,E_l^m=0} \right)
{{\log }_2}\left( 
{\frac{{p\left( {{E_i=0},E_j^t=0,E_k^n=0,E_l^m=0} \right)}}
{{p\left( {{E_i=0}} \right)p\left( {E_j^t=0} \right)
  p\left( {E_k^n=0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m=0} \right)}}} \right)} }
+{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)
{{\log }_2}\left( 
{\frac{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1} \right)}}
{{p\left( {{E_i} = 0} \right)p\left( {E_j^t = 0} \right)
  p\left( {E_k^n = 0} \right)p\left( {E_l^m = 1} \right)}}} \right)}
\end{multline}
```

Comment: Hi ! Please attach a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for us to be able to help !

Comment: @Johannes_B - I don't think this posting is a duplicate -- at least not of the other posting you identified. The *main* problem (among several other problems...) with the present posting is that the OP used a `multline` environment (a good first step!) but failed to provide any line-break instructions. The main problem in the other posting is that while line-break instructions were provided, they had no effect because they were employed in a display math environment (such as `equation`) that doesn't allow line breaks.

Answer (score 2):

With `multline`, long equations do not break magically into lines: you have to specify which line breaks you want. You can add the `fleqn` environment, from `nccmath` to have a nice layout.

Also, you don't need all those pairs braces, so I removed them to have a more readable coe.

```
\documentclass{ieeetran}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{fleqn}
\begin{multline}\label{eq6}
MI\bigl(E,{E^t},E_k^n,E_l^m \bigr) =\\
\sum_i \sum_j p\bigl(E_i=0 ,E_j^t=0,E_k^n=0,E_l^m=0\bigr)\times \\[-1ex]
\log _2 \mathrlap{\Biggl(\frac{p\left(E_i=0, E_j^t=0, E_k^n=0, E_l^m=0\right)}{p\left(E_i=0 \right)p\left(E_j^t=0\right)p\left(E_k^n=0\right)p\left( E_l^m=0 \right)}\Biggr)} \\
{}+p\left(E_i = 0, E_j^t = 0, E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1\right)\times{} \\
\log_2\left(\frac{p\left(E_i = 0, E_j^t = 0, E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1 \right)}{p\left(E_i = 0 \right)p\left(E_j^t = 0\right) p\left(E_k^n = 0\right) p\left( E_l^m = 1 \right)}\right)
\end{multline}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the *math* part of the formula would benefit greatly from the argument of the double sum being encased in `\Biggl[` and `\Biggr]`. :-)  (I know, the symbols are missing in the OP's code too...) :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like this:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}% just for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[3]
\begin{equation}\label{eq6}
\begin{aligned}
&MI( {E,{E^t},E_k^n,E_l^m} ) = {}\\
&\begin{aligned}
\sum_i \sum_j
  &p( E_i=0,E_j^t=0,E_k^n=0,E_l^m=0) \\
  &\cdot\log_2\biggl(\frac{p( E_i=0,E_j^t=0,E_k^n=0,E_l^m=0 )}
                          {p(E_i=0)p(E_j^t=0)p(E_k^n=0)p(E_l^m=0)}
              \biggr) \\
  &+p(E_i = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1)\\
  &\cdot\log_2\biggl(\frac{p(E_i=0,E_j^t=0,E_k^n=0,E_l^m=1)}
                         {p(E_i=0)p(E_j^t=0)p(E_k^n=0)p(E_l^m=1)}
              \biggr)
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

I loaded the `newtx...` packages so to have math in Times font.

I also removed *all* your `\left` and `\right` instructions, most of which simply do damage to spacing. Also most of the braces were either useless or even harmful. For instance, you should never type `{\log}_2`, but only `\log_2`.

[image]

Comment: I think the *math* part of the formula would benefit greatly from the argument of the double sum being encased in `\biggl[` and `\biggr]`. (I know, the symbols are missing in the OP's code too...) :-)

Answer (score 0):

I realize I'm a bit late to the party, but I couldn't resist posting still another solution.

This solution

- inserts 4 explicit line-break instructions (as to the earlier answers);
- omits the unnecessary large round parentheses around the arguments of the `\log_2` terms;
- reduces the value of `\thickmuskip` to achieve tighter spacing around the many `=` symbols; and
- importantly, inserts a pair of currently-missing large square brackets, to emphasize what the argument of the double sum operation is.

The solution also gets rid of all `\left` and `\right` sizing instructions (doing so makes quite a difference in terms of snugging up the terms) and almost all pairs of `{` and `}` grouping symbols; many of them are redundant, and some are actually harmful, e.g., because they prevent the (successful) insertion of line splits.

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'multline' environment
\begin{document}
\setlength{\thickmuskip}{2.5mu}  % default: 5mu
\begin{multline}\label{eq6}
\mathrm{MI}( E,E^t,E_k^n,E_l^m )={}\\ 
\shoveleft{\smash[b]{\sum_i \sum_j\biggl[} 
p(E_i=0,E_j^t=0,E_k^n=0,E_l^m=0)}\\[0.5ex]
\times\log_2 \frac{p(E_i=0,E_j^t=0,E_k^n=0,E_l^m=0)}%
                  {p(E_i=0)p(E_j^t=0) p(E_k^n=0)p(E_l^m=0)} \\[1ex]
\shoveleft{\quad+p(E_i=0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1)} \\
\times\log_2 \frac{p(E_i = 0,E_j^t = 0,E_k^n = 0,E_l^m = 1)}%
                  {p(E_i = 0)p(E_j^t = 0)p(E_k^n = 0)p(E_l^m = 1)} 
\biggr]
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```